# What is the expected behavior when you Add to a List<String> from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

Let's say you have a non synchronized list:

```
List<string> somelist = new List<string>();
```

Now from multiple threads you add to this list:

```
List<ProcessItem> processItems = new List<ProcessItem>();
// Create some items in process items
Parallel.ForEach(processItems, (nextProcessItem) => {
    somelist.Add(nextProcessItem.Id)
});
```

Now we try to use this list in another call:

```
Parallel.ForEach(somelist, (nextListItem) => {
    // Intermittently some nextListItem are coming in null
    Console.Write(nextListItem);
});
```

What is the expected result? I'm trying to debug a client's program and I noticed they were doing something just like this scenario. And the result was certain entries in `somelist` were actually `null` intermittently.

I changed them to `ConcurrentQueue` instead hoping it solves the issue.

Is that the expected behavior one would see from adding to a non-synchronized list in multiple threads?

Comment: Bad Things<sup>TM</sup> Your correct that this is a bug. There's no need to further dissect it.

Comment: Expected behavior only makes sense if you follow the rules. If you don't - there is no expected behavior and anything can happen.

Comment: "Is that the expected behavior one would see from adding to a non-synchronized list in multiple threads?" The reason that there are data structures for multithreaded environments is because there is no consistent expected behavior for a data structure that is not thread safe.

Comment: Can this `Id` be `null`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - does that really matter?

Comment: @bommelding: if his question matters then this is a question that OP has to answer first, because `nextListItem` is the `Id` and OP wonders why it is `null`.

Comment: Look at the [`Add`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,220) method. It consists of 3 lines and all three of them have potential issues if multiple threads are calling it simultaneously.

Comment: Another question that arises is: do you also remove items from the list?

Comment: @TimSchmelter no the id is never null.

Comment: Hi all I read that duplicate question and yes it's very related. but my quesiton in particular is - will that result in a null in the list? because i am fixing the bug telling them this will fix it but i have no way to prove that's definitely the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'expected behaviour' is an exception and/or invalid data.

You only report `null` values but your `somelist` could also have duplicates and missing items.

Run it a little longer and you might see index-out-of-range errors, null reference exceptions etc.